# How to integrate Vaadin as frontend microservice and Spring REST API as backend microservice

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to create two separate microservices. One as frontend with Vaadin Flow and another with Spring Boot REST API with security. The Spring API implements the JWT Security. I want the Vaadin app to call the REST API with user name and password and receive the JWT token as a response.

The Vaadin application authenticates the user for the dashboard. Every request wants to add a bearer token in the header and call the REST API.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I haven't implemented the code yet. In the concept of React after receiving the JWT token, We will store it in the local storage, for every page we will check the token is valid or not. I want to implement the same in Vaadin, Vaadin as a plain UI app not with business logic. Please share some examples to start with.

Comment: Is the backend supposed to be an authentication and authorization server only, or will it also act as a business provider? If only the first, you might as well use Spring Security on you Vaadin MS and implement all authentication and authorization there. I have done this with company LDAP. I might separate the application into frontend and backend at a later time. In that case a authorization server can come in handy (self hosted or online provided). A backend server should probably not handle authentication for the frontend. This should be handled by a third server (authorization server).

Answer (score 1):

This is an simple example using Spring Web RestTemplate connecting to an URL with username and password in header and then receiving a Bearer token. You can use other libraries to achieve the same more or less.

```
// class should be session scoped or bearer put in users session
public class AuthenticateUser {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private final String tokenUrl;
    private String bearer;

    public AuthenticateUser(String tokenUrl) {
        // validate tokenUrl here
        this.tokenUrl = tokenUrl;
    }

    public void authenticate(String username, String password) throws JsonProcessingException {
        // validate username and password here

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("username", username);
        body.add("password", password);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenUrl, entity, String.class);

        if (responseEntity.hasBody()) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(responseEntity.getBody());

            // change access_token to whatever fits your JSON response
            final JsonNode accessToken = jsonNode.get("access_token");
            if (accessToken != null) {
                bearer = accessToken.textValue();
            }
            if (bearer != null && !bearer.trim().equals("")) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No Bearer received");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you have the bearer available you just add it to your header like this and do your POST/GET/DELETE etc.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer); // proof of login
```

Dependencies in this example:

- Spring Web v5.3.9
- Jackson Databind v2.12.4

**Important!**
Bearer TOKEN should be kept in users session and might be saved in uses session store for future reference until TOKEN timeout.

A token timeout can be handled by having a LocalDateTime field paired with the token. Update the field when you authenticate successfully and check the time when you access the bearer. If timed out reauthenticate and update bearer and time. Alternatively if timeout exception just reauthenticate.

I would consider having a separate authorization server handling authentication and authorization rather than having a backend server (running business) being responsible also for authentication and authorization. There is Keycloak, Auth0, Okta, Spring Authorization Server (0.2.0 atm), and more alternatives for you to choose from. Some only as online providers other as self hosted option.

Comment: Thanks, Avec, After receiving the bearer token how can I authorize a user in the front end application with spring security. Because at this point the front application will have only a bearer token no other user data will be available to authorize.

Comment: The bearer token should hold the authorization information when returned. There are many great [Spring Security JWT tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=spring+jwt) online. A great resource for inspecting JWT is https://jwt.io/ 
Hope this helps.